# How to Write more than one data on same cell when export to excell?

Tags: c++, excel, qt

I'm us'ng Qxlsx for export data to excell. Day, month and year data are not coming as a whole, but separately. I can print them one by one while printing them in excel. How can I combine these 3 data and print it?

here is my code for export

```
for (i = 0; i < maxRowCount; ++i) // get maximum data row
  {

    //strList.clear();
    for (j = 0; j < 7; ++j) 
    {
   /* 
            j[0] = Temp Değeri
            j[1] = Humadity      
            j[2] = Day      
            j[3] = moon       
            j[4] = Year      
            j[5] = Second   
            j[6] = Minute   
            j[7] = Hour     


        */

      if (i < dataColums[j].count()) {

      

        format.setNumberFormatIndex(2); // for save as number format 
      
        
if (j == 0)  
        {
          xlsx.write(k, 3, dataColums[j][i], format); 
         
        }
        else if(j==1) 
        {
          xlsx.write(k, 4, dataColums[j][i], format); 
          
        }

        else if(j==2  ) 
        {
//here I need write day moon and year when j=2 But I cannot write 3 data on same time.

       }

    }
    k = k + 1;

  }
```

Comment: What is the type of `dataColums`?

Comment: Also, your code is cluttered by a for-switch antipattern. It would be cleaner if you just wrote the lines in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want `QString::arg`:

```
xlsx.write(k, 5, QString("%1/%2/%3").arg(dataColums[4][i]).arg(dataColums[3][i]).arg(dataColums[2][i]));
```

As an aside, you can make your code a lot cleaner if you eliminate the for-switch pattern:

```
format.setNumberFormatIndex(2);

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
  maxRowCount = min(maxRowCount, dataColums[j].count());
}

for (i = 0; i < maxRowCount; i++, k++) {
    xlsx.write(k, 3, dataColums[0][i], format); 
    xlsx.write(k, 4, dataColums[1][i], format); 
    xlsx.write(k, 5, QString("%1/%2/%3").arg(dataColums[4][i]).arg(dataColums[3][i]).arg(dataColums[2][i]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer it's worked well. Can I ask you another question about program waits too mush when export huge data?

Comment: This is a FAQ. [For example, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149643/qt-program-hangs-not-responding-until-function-ends-then-starts-working-again)

Comment: I've had a look at using Thread, thanks for the FAQ. My question to you, it takes me a few hours to export two hundred thousand data to excel, do you think this is normal? In my previous attempt, I was able to export thirty thousand data in 11 minutes. Is this time normal for you?

Comment: No, that is ridiculously slow, assuming you measured just the writing time.

Comment: can you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73417492/exporting-data-to-excel-takes-hours)  please.